# How to prevent re-checking already-checked data?

Tags: validation, efficiency

I have a class with a `validId($id)` method that is called by the constructor and by `public function load($id)`. The method queries the database to see if the id exists and returns true/false.

The constructor optionally takes an `$id` (if no $id, then the object will be empty).

The constructor checks the $id with `validId($id)`, and if it passes, then it calls `load($id)`.

I should not take `validId()` out of `load()` because `load()` is public and the input has to be checked!

The same goes for the constructor.

How do I avoid calling `validId()` twice? I was thinking I could add a parameter to `load($id,$check_id)`, but that would be ridiculous. You can't give clients the option to not validate data!

I could add a protected property like `$id_is_valid` that gets set to true by `validId($id)`. But how do I know the value that was valid is the same one being received by my `load()` method?

I'm using PHP.

Hopefully this isn't a stupid question.

Answer (score 2):

If the constructor calls `load($id)` (which calls `validId` by itself), why does it has to call `validId` first? Let it call `load($id)` unconditionally, make sure `load($id)` returns some status to show if the id was valid or not, so the constructor can act accordingly.

This suggestion will work, but it is still not the cleanest one. Better create an additional, private method `load_unchecked($id)` and call this from the constructor as well as from `load`. This gives you the control you want.